# relationship SQL C# with linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm studying Linq, I have a table with a relationship between processos.idProcesso and ProcessosDetalhe.id_ProcessosDetalhe, but, when I try to add the informations in DataBase, I get one error:

[image: Error]

[image: DataBase]

I tried to use the Add function, but, I can't use the add function in datacontex
So, how I can solve that error ??
or, what I need to make in SQL to correct that error ?

[image: Add error datacontext]

Comment: What kind of object is ProcDet.ProcessosDetalhes?? Is it an IEnumerable? In that case, it wont allow 'Add'.

Comment: var ProcDet = new ProcessosDetDataContext();

Comment: And ProcessosDetalhes is a DbSet? Just to confirm.

Comment: ProcessosDetalhe is a table, look the picture of the tables... ;)

Comment: Yes, I get that it's a table. I was thinking in terms of entity framework, so mentioned dbset. I am just trying to think how the tables are mapped as entities since you are not getting the 'Add' option.

Answer (score 0):

The error mean that in your table ProcessosDetalhes, it has a foreign key reference to another table. The FK cannot have a value in that column that is not also in the primary key column of the referenced table.

Comment: Strange... I tried to first insert the values of Processo table, after this, I start to process the values of ProcessosDetalhes, but, I got the same error, I have the value in Processo table, but, now work :(